# How to bind collections with same type on same level in TreeView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I want to display the following collection in a Treeview

```
 private ObservableCollection<SectionHeader> _sections;
 public ObservableCollection<SectionHeader> Sections
 {
     get { return _sections ?? (_sections = new ObservableCollection<SectionHeader>()); }
     set { _sections = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Sections); }
 }
```

Here is how SectionHeader and nested types look like

```
 public class SectionHeader
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<SectionItem> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<SectionItem> Items { get { return _items ?? (_items = new ObservableCollection<SectionItem>()); } }
}

public class SectionItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }


    private ObservableCollection<ProductCalculatorTemplate> _products;
    public ObservableCollection<ProductCalculatorTemplate> Products { get { return _products ?? (_products = new ObservableCollection<ProductCalculatorTemplate>()); } }

    private ObservableCollection<ProductCalculatorTemplate> _productsOptionTwo;
    public ObservableCollection<ProductCalculatorTemplate> ProductsOptionTwo { get { return _productsOptionTwo ?? (_productsOptionTwo = new ObservableCollection<ProductCalculatorTemplate>()); } }
}

public class ProductCalculatorTemplate
{
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public double NoOfCoats { get; set; }
    public double PackSize { get; set; }
}
```

And here is how my XAML code for TreeView looks like

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Sections}" Background="GhostWhite">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType= "{x:Type ViewModels:SectionHeader}" ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=Items}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType = "{x:Type ViewModels:SectionItem}" ItemsSource = "{Binding Path=Products}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType = "{x:Type ViewModels:ProductCalculatorTemplate}" >
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Product}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
 </TreeView>
```

This is the output of the above code

[image]
But I want to display the information in a way that below Fenomastic there appears a child node named "Option 1" which should list down all Prdoucts and 2nd child of Fenomastic should be "Option 2" which should list down all ProductsOptionTwo member of SectionItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only the basic tree view in WPF the simplest option would be to introduce an Options Collection, that would contain Option 1 and Option 2 as items i.e.:

```
public class SectionItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<Option> _options;
    public ObservableCollection<Option> Options
    {
        get { return _options ?? (_options = new ObservableCollection<Option>()); }
    }
}

public class Option
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ProductCalculatorTemplate> Products
    {
        get { return _products ?? (_products = new ObservableCollection<ProductCalculatorTemplate>()); }
    }
}
```

And adding another `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for the `Option` type

As the `TreeView` otherwise isn't suitable for listing a nonvariable amount of properties like your `ProductsOption` and `ProductsOptionTwo` properties are.